# CodenameOne - encoding HTML string

Tags: java, html, codenameone, html-encode, textutils

My CodenameOne app needs to pass HTML code to HTML elements inside a BrowserComponent with Javascript, so characters have to be escaped more than one time, they have to be encoded in fact.

I need something like `TextUtils.htmlEncode()`.

In Codename it seems to be `HTMLUtils` but is deprecated, and I am not sure there is the equivalent method.

So what is the equivalent of `TextUtils.htmlEncode()` in CodenameOne?

Comment: Try: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Util.html#encodeBody-java.lang.String-

Comment: `HTMLUtils` is from an old HTML rendering implementation which is no longer available. @FrancescoGalgani is correct that's the encode function

Answer (score 1):

In fact I just need to manage double quotes for the srcdoc parameter of iFrames, so if I am not wrong the solution is to replace

```
"
```

with

```
\"
```

In Java:

```
String htmlText=originalHTMLToEmbed.replace("\"","\\\"");
```

I tried it and it works.

If more levels are involved in HTML, they are already escaped, so occurrences of

```
\\\"
```

(and so on) are possible to be found in the final string.